# came closer in his car / came closer with his car?

Tags: prepositions

Prepositions are always a bit tricky in English.
Should I say: "He came closer **with** his car to watch her from his car window".
Or : "He came closer **in** his car to watch her from his car window".

Comment: Both are acceptable. The latter emphasises that he is **in** the car; the former implies it. More common might be: **He brought the car closer....**

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either is OK. "With" may place slightly more emphasis on the movement of the car. "In" may place slightly more emphasis on the movement of the driver.

Neither seem to say exactly what you mean if I am reading you correctly. What I think you are trying to convey is that he took action to see her better without getting out of the car, closer but not too close. The car after all is not an independent actor. I might try "To see her better through the car window, he drove closer."

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for your suggestion.